# Python Django - how to show model changes on a page without refreshing it using Ajax?

Tags: javascript, python, django, ajax, django-models

Python Django. I have a model:

```
 class text(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField('Текст' ,blank = False)
    time =  models.CharField('Время',max_length = 200,blank = False)
```

And I output them all in html:

```
   {% for object in text %}
           <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xl-3 block_messeage">
        <span class="span_block_messeage"> ,{{object.time}}</span>
                <br>
               {{object.text}}
      </div>
   </div> 

    {% endfor %}
```

everything is displayed successfully, but the class text is increasing every second and I need to show these changes without refreshing the page. How can this be implemented using ajax?

Comment: you should use django channels

Comment: The simplest way is to create an API/view that returns the data you need and then create some JS that polls that API for updated data